# Showing NSView subclass over other view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, addsubview

I'm trying to show a custom NSView over another view in a OS X App. This is the custom View. It's just a red box:

```
@interface HelpBarView : NSView

@end

@implementation HelpBarView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self)
    {
        NSLog(@"init");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    NSLog(@"draw");
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    NSRectFill(self.bounds);
}

@end
```

To show this view over another view:

```
HelpBarView* hbv = [[HelpBarView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 20, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:hbv];
```

This won't show the view. But i can see from the log, that both methods are being called. Also in the XCode Debug View Hierarchy i can see, that the box is in front of the other view and in the correct position. But in the real programm it's not visible.

Also if i do this:

```
[self.view setSubviews:[NSArray arrayWithObject:hbv]];
```

Then it will be shown but all other subviews are missing, so this is not what i want.

What am i missing? How can i show a view above another view?

Comment: Did you try calling `[NSBezierPath fillRect:self.bounds];` instead of `NSRectFill(self.bounds);`?

Comment: makes no difference. It's still not visible

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you need to add this line to your NSView subclass's `-initWithFrame` method:

```
self.wantsLayer = YES;
```

This solved all my problems of the subview not showing up on screen, even though it showed up in Xcode's debug hierarchy view.